# C: Text file matrix to 2d array

Tags: c

Hi I am new to C language and I want to know how I can pass a matrix that exists as a text file and looks like this:

```
1 169.059 
2 169.524 
3 169.952 
4 170.342 
...
```

to 2-d array format in C. Thanks.

Comment: [`fscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is the typical way of reading formatted data from a file.

Comment: [Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about _what you have tried_ and exactly what you are trying to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) I want to help you, I really do, but you need to try breaking this down into reasonable chunks and looking for the answers to those (e.g. how to open a file, how to read a integer from a text file in C, how to read a float, how to make a 2D array...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input sample you've shown represent a specific case of a 2d matrix (a matrix with 2 columns). But, if that's what you want, here it is:

```
FILE *fin = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); // Used to open the file.
double array[1000][2];                  // 1000 is the maximum number of entries
                                        // The array has data type double in
                                        // order to be able to store the data in
                                        // the second column
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)             // n is the number of entries.
    fscanf(fin, "%g %g", &array[i][0], &array[i][1]);
```

Note that this is by no means the best method to store data of the type you've shown. A better approach would be to store it an a unidimensional array, and use indices to encode the first part.